# How to integrate keyboard with autofillservice in android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, autofill

How to make autofill suggestions appear in a bar above keyboard instead of box next to input field? Kotlin

I'm learning mechanisms of Autofill on android. So far I created an app which holds list of login, password and app package name and provides autofill service to other apps. Unfortunatelly autofill doesn't work in all apps. But I can see that it works fine with at least some of apps. Now after hitting input field, the box appears next to field and after pressing a box, data is autofilled (both login & password). [1: I hit login field and box appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amQgG.png) [2: I hit box and both login & password are autofilled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzLo3.png) Other app: [1st step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgH2T.png) [2nd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Obl.png). I still need to work out why doesn't it work in other apps(tried windy, tiktok, kfc), but it's not a current question.

Now I try to make autofill suggestion apper in vertical bar above the keyboard, instead of boxes next to input fields. Such feature is aviable since andorid 11. I've read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/ime-autofill) and have been trying various ways for few days so far, but didn't reach the solution.
Should it be implemented inside a class that extends AutofillService, or I need to create a new class which extends InputMethodService (IME) and implement solution inside of it?
My code looks like that:

```
class CustomAutoFillServiceIME : AutofillService() {
    @SuppressLint("Recycle", "RemoteViewLayout")
    override fun onFillRequest(
        request: FillRequest,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
        callback: FillCallback
    ) {
        try{
            val structure =
                request.fillContexts[request.fillContexts.size - 1].structure
            val emailFields: MutableList<ViewNode?> = ArrayList()
            val passFields: MutableList<ViewNode?> = ArrayList()
            val appName = structure.activityComponent.packageName

            identifyEmailFields(structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode, emailFields)
            identifyPassFields(structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode, passFields)

            val credentialsList = listOf(
                AppCredentials("com.example.abc", "x@x.com", "xx","ABC test"),
                AppCredentials("com.example.filltests", "login", "password","Filltests sample"),
                AppCredentials("com.windyty.android", "Adam xTest", "xxx","Windy Adam"),
                AppCredentials("pl.mapa_turystyczna.app", "LoginTest", "PassTest","Mapa Turystyczna sample"),
                AppCredentials("com.kfc_polska", "LoginTestKFC", "PassTestKFC","KFC sample"),
                AppCredentials("com.example.aaa", "login", "password","AAA sample")
            )

            val datasets = mutableListOf<Dataset>()

            for (credential in credentialsList.filter { it.appName == appName }) {
                // Make sure you have found both email and password fields
                if (emailFields.isNotEmpty() && passFields.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val emailField = emailFields[0]
                    val passField = passFields[0]

                    val remoteView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.autofill_suggestion)
                    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.suggestion_item, credential.name)

                    val dataSetBuilder = Dataset.Builder(remoteView)

                    emailField?.autofillId?.let { autofillId ->
                        dataSetBuilder.setValue(autofillId, AutofillValue.forText(credential.login))
                    }
                    passField?.autofillId?.let { autofillId ->
                        dataSetBuilder.setValue(autofillId, AutofillValue.forText(credential.password))
                    }

                    datasets.add(dataSetBuilder.build())
                }
            }

            val responseBuilder = FillResponse.Builder()

            datasets.forEach { dataset ->
                responseBuilder.addDataset(dataset)
            }

            callback.onSuccess(responseBuilder.build())

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("XD", "Error during onFillRequest", e)
            callback.onFailure(e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }

    private fun identifyEmailFields(
        node: ViewNode,
        emailFields: MutableList<ViewNode?>
    ) {
        //check by autofillHints if exists:
        if (node.autofillHints != null) {
            Log.e("XD", node.autofillHints.toString())
            if (node.autofillHints!!.contains("email") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("username") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("login") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("user") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("usr") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("user name") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("identifier") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("id")
            ) {
                Log.e("XD", "identifyEmailField detected autofillhints")
                emailFields.add(node)
                return
            }
        }

        //check by id, if autofillHints don't exist:
        if (node.className != null && node.className!!.contains("EditText")) {
            Log.e("XD", "identifyEmailField didn't detect autofillhints")
            val viewId = node.idEntry
            if (viewId != null && (viewId.contains("email") ||
                        viewId.contains("username") ||
                        viewId.contains("login") ||
                        viewId.contains("user") ||
                        viewId.contains("usr") ||
                        viewId.contains("user name") ||
                        viewId.contains("identifier") ||
                        viewId.contains("id"))
            ) {
                emailFields.add(node)
                return
            }
        }

        for (i in 0 until node.childCount) {
            identifyEmailFields(node.getChildAt(i), emailFields)
        }
    }

    private fun identifyPassFields(
        node: ViewNode,
        passFields: MutableList<ViewNode?>
    ) {
        if (node.autofillHints != null) {
            Log.e("XD", node.autofillHints.toString())
            if (node.autofillHints!!.contains("password") ||
                node.autofillHints!!.contains("pass")
            ) {
                passFields.add(node)
                return
            }
        }

        if (node.className != null && node.className!!.contains("EditText")) {
            val viewId = node.idEntry
            if (viewId != null && (viewId.contains("password") ||
                        viewId.contains("pass"))
            ) {
                passFields.add(node)
                return
            }
        }

        for (i in 0 until node.childCount) {
            identifyPassFields(node.getChildAt(i), passFields)
        }
    }


    override fun onSaveRequest(request: SaveRequest, callback: SaveCallback) {
    }

}
```

If it matters, I add that I use Gboard as keyboard on device which I use and test on it.